# Setting up UNC paths with GCP FileStore

Tags: google-compute-engine, google-cloud-filestore

I'm really new at GCP.

At this time we have Multiple MSSQL Servers that heavily use UNC paths, and in trying to setup the filestore, mount it to a windows VM, I cannot seem to get UNC paths to work at all in the Microsoft Server 2019 instance to use UNC paths.

Does GCP support UNC paths from File Store.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, GCP supports UNC paths for the [File Store](https://cloud.google.com/architecture/filers-on-compute-engine).
The most common protocols for exporting file shares are Server Message Block (SMB) for Windows and Network File System (NFS) for Linux (and in some cases Windows).

You can map/mount an SMB share created with Cloud Volumes Service by using its uniform naming convention (UNC) path, which the UI displays.

This [document](https://cloud.google.com/architecture/partners/netapp-cloud-volumes/faqs-netapp#why_cant_my_client_resolve_the_smb_netbios_name) has FAQs and suggestions on the working of SMB.

**Note:**

Cloud Volumes Service doesn't let you use more than 10 characters for the cloud volumes SMB name.

A UNC path follows the pattern \<sharename> (for example, \cvssmb-d2e6.cvsdemo.internal\quirky-youthful-hermann).